# What happens with /media if you run "rm -rf /"?

Tags: disk, delete, rm

```
rm -rf /
rm -rf /*
rm -rf --no-preserve-root /
```

We know those commands will delete all possible files in /, but what would happen to the files of the disks mounted on /media?
Likewise, what would happen to the files within the symbolic links going to /media disks?

I know the command is dangerously destructive, especially on UEFI systems so I think I know the answer but I want to be sure.

Obviously, I'm not asking this because I want to try it, but just out of curiosity.

Comment: It'll `rm` any files mounted & accessible (to the user who ran the command assuming file-system is RW and not RO). What *file-system* they are on (local, remote, network, external) doesn't matter if the user as access rights & file-system is RW (not for example RO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run that, Everything you can delete under `/media` is gone and all links to them will be broken.

If someone else has something mounted there. That's safe from your removal.

If you run it using `sudo`. Then everything is gone.